# how do i build libraries in subdirectories using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

My code is organized like this:

- cpp

  - main.cpp (calls code from `dataStructures/` and `common/`)
  - CMakeLists.txt (*topmost* CMakeLists file)
  - build
  - common

    - CMakeLists.txt (should be responsible for building common shared library)
    - include

      - utils.h
    - src

      - utils.cpp
    - build
  - dataStructures

    - CMakeLists.txt (build dataStructures shared library - dependent on common library)
    - include

      - dsLinkedList.h
    - src

      - dsLinkedList.cpp
    - build

`build\` directories contain the built target. The actual code can be seen here: https://github.com/brainydexter/PublicCode/tree/master/cpp

As of now, CMakeLists.txt in each of the subdirectories build their own shared libraries. Topmost CMakeLists file then references the libraries and paths like this

**Topmost CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(cpp)

#For the shared library:
set ( PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libcppDS.dylib libcppCommon.dylib)
link_directories( dataStructures/build )
link_directories( common/build )

#Bring the headers, into the project
include_directories(common/include)
include_directories(dataStructures/include)

#Can manually add the sources using the set command as follows:
set(MAINEXEC main.cpp)

add_executable(testDS ${MAINEXEC})
target_link_libraries(testDS ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} )
```

**How can I change the topmost CMakeLists.txt to go into subdirectories (`common` and `dataStructures`) and build their targets if they haven't been built, without me having to manually build the individual libraries ?**

CMakeLists for **common** :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(cpp_common)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

#Bring the headers, such as Student.h into the project
include_directories(include)

#However, the file(GLOB...) allows for wildcard additions:
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

#Generate the shared library from the sources
add_library(cppCommon SHARED ${SOURCES})
```

**dataStructures** :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(cpp_dataStructures)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

#For the shared library:
set ( PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libcppCommon.dylib )
link_directories( ../common/build )

#Bring the headers, such as Student.h into the project
include_directories(include)
include_directories(../common/include/)

#However, the file(GLOB...) allows for wildcard additions:
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

#Generate the shared library from the sources
add_library(cppDS SHARED ${SOURCES})
```

Update:

This pull request helped me understand the correct way of doing this:
https://github.com/brainydexter/PublicCode/pull/1

and commitId: 4b4f1d3d24b5d82f78da3cbffe423754d8c39ec0 [on my git](https://github.com/brainydexter/PublicCode/commit/4b4f1d3d24b5d82f78da3cbffe423754d8c39ec0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are only missing a simple thing: `add_subdirectory`.
From the documentation:

> `add_subdirectory(source_dir [binary_dir] [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL])`
>
> Add a subdirectory to the build. The source_dir specifies the directory in which the source CMakeLists.txt and code files are located. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated with respect to the current directory (the typical usage), but it may also be an absolute path. The binary_dir specifies the directory in which to place the output files. If it is a relative path it will be evaluated with respect to the current output directory, but it may also be an absolute path.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html

It does exactly what you need.

Comment: When I calll `add_subdirectory(common) add_subdirectory(dataStructures)`, and I delete the `libcppDS.dylib` from `cpp\dataStructures\build`. This is the same as no libraries have been built before calling topmost CMakeLists.txt. When I try to run `make`, linker complains that `-lcppDS library not found`. @ypnos : How can I fix this ?

Comment: I was able to make it work by removing `link_directories( dataStructures/build )`.

Comment: Does `add_subdirectory()` add the files in that subdirectory to the build of the main program, or does it actually create a `.a` file that can be linked during the build?

Comment: What it does is that it executes the CMakeLists.txt file in that subdirectory. In the file you can both build an object to be linked and add it to the main target, or add separate code files to the main target.